# ActionBarSherlock padding and margin

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using the `actionbarsherlock` and `TabStrip Sliding Pager` library so that my application may look like the Play Store.

The problem is when I use the `ActionBarSherlock` and the NavigationTabs from `PagerSlidingTabStrip`. A small padding or margin below the actionbar appears.

This does not occur in the sample application of the original TabStrip Sliding Pager library. (can be found in playstore at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample)

The sample of PagerSlidingTabStrip does not use the `ActionBarSherlock`:
[image]

Here is on my Droid 2.3.3
[image]

Here is my aplication whit ABS:
[image]

And the last image of my application without `ActionBarSherlcok`, which reveals that the problem is precisely the `ActionBarSherlock`.
As you can see here the NavigationBar looks as it should
[image]

How can i fix it?
In advance thank you very much

Comment: It looks like the "original" example has the same visual behavior, but you just haven't magnified it as much as your examples.  Try hiding the Action Bar and see if it still shows up.

Comment: Is there any padding added?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski no, I try to delete any magin or padding in the layout and code.
Original application does not use the Action bar sherlock, and looks perfect on my phone 2.3.3 (margin is not at first). I put another picture for you to see.

I will try to hide the action bar, to give more details

Comment: @louielouie as you can see, the problem is ABS. There any way to remove the paddin?

Comment: This looks like just a difference in background colours, not so much as padding. Go to the developer options, turn on "Show layout bounds", and actually confirm what you are seeing. Also, why would you post the same question twice?

Comment: @LuckyMe I'm using android sttudio, where can i find that?

Comment: @OscarMéndez That is in your Android device, where the app is installed, settings -> Developer Options -> Drawing -> Show layout bounds. Then compare what you see in the apps.

Comment: @LuckyMe On my Droid the root is: setting-> Applications-> Dvelopment->
But only shows: USB debugging, Stay awake, and Allow mock locations

Comment: That's why I use developer devices for developing. Try going to About Phone and repeatedly tab the "Build Number" item about 10 times, I think it was, and that should enable the developer options, go back to developer and see if anything changes. If that doesn't work, then unfortunately, I don't know how to enable it.